# Select() implemented wrong in program, getting timeouts from server

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, select, file-descriptor

A third question in the saga: [How to correctly implement select to correctly get data from stdin and recv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775899/). I recommend reading this and the other question it links to understand the situation.

Basically, I tried my luck at implementing `select()` myself. My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argv[1] == NULL) {
        cout << "\033[31mTARGET NOT SPECIFIED - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -1;
    }
    if (argv[2] == NULL) {
        cout << "\033[31mPORT NOT SPECIFIED - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -2;
    }
    
    string target = argv[1];
    int port = atoi(argv[2]);

    cout << "GENERATING SOCKET...\n";
    int chatter = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (chatter == -1) {
        cout << "\033[31mSOCKET GENERATION FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -3;
    }
    cout << "\033[32mSUCCESSFULLY GENERATED SOCKET\033[0m\n";

    struct sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port   = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, target.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_usec = 0.0;
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    int recval;

    cout << "CONNECTING TO " << target << " AT PORT " << port << "...\n";   
    int connection_status = connect(chatter, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connection_status == -1) {
        cout << "\033[31mCONNECTION FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -4;
    }
    cout << "\033[32mCONNECTED TO HOST\033[0m\n";

    char buf[4096] = {0};
    string msg;
    while (true) {
        fd_set rfds;
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(chatter, &rfds);

        getline(cin, msg);
        msg+"\r\n";
        int sendmsg = send(chatter, msg.c_str(), msg.size()+1, 0);
        if (sendmsg == -1) {
            cout << "\033[31mMESSAGE SENDING FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
            return -5;
        }

        recval = select(chatter + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        switch(recval) {
            case(0):
                cout << "\033[31mTIMEOUT\033[0m\n";
                break;
            case(-1):
                cout << "\033[31mERROR\033[0m\n";
                break;
            default:
                if (recv(chatter, buf, 4096, 0) < 0) {
                    cout << "\033[31mFAILURE TO RECEIVE MESSAGE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                    return -6;
                } else {
                    cout << recv(chatter, buf, 4096, 0) << "\n";
                    cout << buf << "\n";
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    close(chatter);

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting `TIMEOUT` when trying the program on `scanme.nmap.org` and my HTTP server. What am I doing wrong?

At this point, after fixing something a user in the first question pointed out, I know that there isn't an issue with how I'm sending data. Just an issue with the way the program handles getting data from `getline()`/`recv()`.

**EDIT: NEW, IMPROVED, WORKING CODE THANKS TO ANSWERER**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argv[1] == NULL) {
        cout << "\033[31mTARGET NOT SPECIFIED - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -1;
    }
    if (argv[2] == NULL) {
        cout << "\033[31mPORT NOT SPECIFIED - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -2;
    }
    
    string target = argv[1];
    int port = atoi(argv[2]);

    cout << "GENERATING SOCKET...\n";
    int chatter = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (chatter == -1) {
        cout << "\033[31mSOCKET GENERATION FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -3;
    }
    cout << "\033[32mSUCCESSFULLY GENERATED SOCKET\033[0m\n";

    struct sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port   = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, target.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    int recval;

    cout << "CONNECTING TO " << target << " AT PORT " << port << "...\n";   
    int connection_status = connect(chatter, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connection_status == -1) {
        cout << "\033[31mCONNECTION FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -4;
    }
    cout << "\033[32mCONNECTED TO HOST\033[0m\n";

    char buf[4096] = {0};
    string msg;
    while (true) {
        struct timeval tv;
        tv.tv_usec = 0.0;
        tv.tv_sec = 5;

        fd_set rfds;
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(chatter, &rfds);

        getline(cin, msg);
        msg += "\r\n";
        const char *pMsg = msg.c_str();
        size_t msgSize = msg.size();
        do {
            int numSent = send(chatter, pMsg, msgSize, 0);
            if (numSent == -1) {
                cout << "\033[31mMESSAGE SENDING FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                close(chatter);
                return -5;
            }
            pMsg += numSent;
            msgSize -= numSent;
        } while (msgSize > 0);

        recval = select(chatter + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        switch(recval) {
            case(0):
                cout << "\033[31mTIMEOUT\033[0m\n";
                break;
            case(-1):
                cout << "\033[31mERROR\033[0m\n";
                break;
            default:
                int numRead = recv(chatter, buf, 4096, 0);
                if (numRead < 0) {
                    cout << "\033[31mFAILURE TO RECEIVE MESSAGE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                    close(chatter);
                    return -6;
                }
                else if (numRead == 0) {
                    cout << "\033[31mDISCONNECTED - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                    close(chatter);
                    break;
                } else {
                    cout << numRead << "\n";
                    cout.write(buf, numRead);
                    cout << "\n";
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    close(chatter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `chatter + 1` where does the +1 come from? (Not saying it's an issue, just asking to be sure the question is clear)

Comment: I don't see an attempt at _implementing_ `select`. Did you mean _use_?

Comment: @Jeffrey To be quite honest I don't know I just saw that in an example. I'm going to try the advice of an answerer on this and if it works I'll just leave it, if it doesn't I'll try removing it.

Comment: @Jeffrey Regarding the `+1`: "_This argument should be set to the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1._" (from `man select` on Linux). If I remember correctly, the Windows version of `select` doesn't care. Edit: Yepp, from MSDN: "_Ignored. The nfds parameter is included only for compatibility with Berkeley sockets._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some platforms, `select()` alters the passed `timeval` to indicate how much time is remaining.  So this is likely the cause of your timeout errors, as you are setting the `timeval` only once and it will eventually fall to 0. You need to reset your `tv` variable every time you call `select()`, so move that inside your `while` loop.

Also, you have 2 calls to `recv()` where you should be using only 1 call. You are ignoring the bytes received by the 1st `recv()`, and if the server happens to send less then 4096 bytes then there won't be any data left for the *next* call to `select()` to detect, unless the connection is disconnected.

Change this:

```cpp
if (recv(chatter, buf, 4096, 0) < 0) {
    cout << "\033[31mFAILURE TO RECEIVE MESSAGE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
    return -6;
} else {
    cout << recv(chatter, buf, 4096, 0) << "\n";
    cout << buf << "\n";
}
```

To this:

```cpp
int numRead = recv(chatter, buf, 4096, 0);
if (numRead < 0) {
    cout << "\033[31mFAILURE TO RECEIVE MESSAGE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
    return -6;
}
else if (numRead == 0) {
    cout << "\033[32mHOST DISCONNECTED\033[0m\n";
    break;
} else {
    cout << numRead << "\n";
    cout.write(buf, numRead);
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Also, `msg+"\r\n";` is a no-op, you probably meant to use `msg += "\r\n";` instead.

And, you should not be including the `msg`'s null terminator when calling `send()`.  And you are not accounting for the possibility that `send()` *may not* be able to send the whole data in one go.  You need to call `send()` in a loop instead, eg:

```cpp
const char *pMsg = msg.c_str();
size_t msgSize = msg.size();

do {
    int numSent = send(chatter, pMsg, msgSize, 0);
    if (numSent == -1) {
        cout << "\033[31mMESSAGE SENDING FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
        return -5;
    }
    pMsg += numSent;
    msgSize -= numSent;
}
while (msgSize > 0);
```

Comment: Your advice on sending/receiving improved the code though it was your point on `tv` that got it to actually work. I have the new code with your suggestions if you want to check it over.

Comment: If the code works, and you just want to improve it now, then you should ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.